# Shading above and below lines in line graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Would greatly appreciate help on this...

I need to shade above a line (i.e. between that line and the top of the graph) as well as below another line.

It's a river flow graph and the objective is to highlight another line that is mostly between the two lines I need to add shading to.

image one is the graph - linked below. I'm trying to shade above the blue and below the red
[image: image one is the graph - linked below. I'm trying to shade above the blue and below the red]

All the tutorials and questions I've found relate to shading between two lines or making the graph into an area graph - neither of which is a great fit.

Here's links to things I've found:

https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_vAhGwjWzA

THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you show a mock example of what you're looking to do, and what you've tried?

Comment: Question edited for clarification. Let me know if you have more questions. THANKS!

Comment: Why is an area chart "not a good fit"? It's about the only way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, The area chart automatically stacks the values - not what I'm trying to do. I also haven't found a way for the "area" to show above rather than below the line. A suggestion for how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: You can deal with the stacked area chart, in fact, it's preferred. You need three areas, one to fill below the red line, one transparent one between the red and blue lines, and one to fill between the blue line and an imaginary line at the top of the chart. Once you visualize that, it's a straightforward implementation of my tutorial that you've already found. And it's especially easy if you're starting with a line chart, so you don't need to convert scatter chart X coordinates into area chart X coordinates, since lines and areas use the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Insert a combo chart

2) For the lower and upper values select Area (*not stacked area* chart type)

[image]

3) For the middole value, select Line chart type

4) Click "OK" -- you will likely not see the areas like you want it, the higher value may hide the lower value area -- this is normal

5) Right click on the chart and choose "Select Data"

6) Move each series up or down so all data becomes visible by clicking on the two triangles -- the chart should update as you go.

[image]

7) Once the chart is all right, click "OK"

8) Select the Plot Area, Right Click on it and Choose Format Plot Area, then choose whatever colour you want for the fill

You should end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey - thanks for your answer. Not quite what I'm looking for though - I'd like to shade the *entire* area above and below the lines.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: SO helpful!!! This worked well. I made the blue and red lines area chart. Blue with white fill so that the other two lines showed through (stacked those on top). Red line with solid red fill. And then formatted the plot area with a solid blue fill.    You are a wizard. Thanks.